# Validate typescript definition files for errors programatically

Tags: typescript, compilation

I am generating typescript definition files programmatically. Sometimes an incorrect definition file will be generated from user error. This cannot be changed and is irrelevant.

```
export type Test = {
    prop: number
}

export interface Example {
  test: string;               // Error since not of type Test
  [k: string]: Test; 
}
```

I am trying to programmatically check this definition file to see if I get errors. For example, if I create a file for testing purposes with a single import;

```
import * as TestImport from './example';
```

and then use the typescript compiler from command line, I will get an error as expected;

```sh
$ npx tsc --noEmit test.ts
$ error TS2411: Property 'test' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'Test'.

5     test: string;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is a good step, and perhaps as a fall back I will look into simply using `npx` programmatically.

However, for now I am trying to use `tsc` directly, but I am getting no error on compilation;

```
import { transpile } from "typescript";
import { readFile } from "fs/promises"

const data: string = (await readFile(`./example.ts`)).toString();
transpile(data, { strict: true });
```

I tried using `transpileModule` too but nothing. I also tried dynamic imports out of desperation, but runtime imports obviously don't influence typescript defintions.

I'm stumped as to why `tsc` from the command line seems to find this import issue with definitions but `transpile` does not. Is `transpile` even the correct method to use? Am I missing compilation options? Do I need to write a basic [custom compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)?

Answer (score 1):

I've been fiddling around with this yesterday to test type challenge solutions and here's what I found so far.

Create a new Program:

```
import ts from "typescript";

const program = ts.createProgram({
    // ...
});
```

Provide the compiler options:

```
const program = ts.createProgram({
    options: { ... },
});
```

Provide the entry point:

```
const program = ts.createProgram({
    // ...
    rootNames: ["./check-this-file.ts"],
});
```

Then call `emit` and check the diagnostics:

```
const { diagnostics } = program.emit();
```

It will be an array of Diagnostic objects which you can log and see what's included in there (diagnostic message, location, code, etc).

A pretty basic custom compiler if you ask me

Comment: Humm, I tried this and still get no errors in the diagnostics - even with the same ts configuration as the CLI command uses.

Comment: Is the entry point correct?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but have you tried running `ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)`? My diagnostic array is empty, but `getPreEmitDiagnostics` does return the expected validation errors